# Trouble with jQuery's .animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using .animate() to smoothly reposition a few divs after they've been made visible via .show("slow"). Since the divs may or may not still be doing the animation, I'm also using .queue() to make sure the move takes place after the animation's done.

Problem: .animate() doesn't work. It gets to the right line of code, but doesn't do anything and doesn't generate any errors. Help?

Javascript:

```
function arrange_sections() {
        var margin = 20;
        var left = margin;
        $(".section.active").queue(function() {
            $(".section.active").each(function() {
                $(this).animate({ "left": left }, "slow");
                left += $(this).width() + margin;
            });
        });
}
```

CSS:
(I use show("slow") to bring the sections out of display:none)

```
.section {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    padding: 20px;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Comment: Should '.section' and '.active' clases have a space between them '.section .active'). In other words: have you checked that the css path query finds the elements you want? You might also want to assign the result of $('.section.active') to a variable instead of creating the objects twice.

Comment: I am meaning to select the intersection of .section and .active, so yes, the no-space is correct. Using Firebug I've determined it gets to the .animate() line, and if I replace the .animate() line with a different function, like .css(), it works fine.

Comment: Aleksi -- you were right about creating $('.section.active') twice. I originally had "$(this)", but changed it thinking (for some reason) that queue() would only affect the first object if more than one object was selected.

In fact I inadvertently caused my function to be called more than I wanted it to be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer -- All I needed to do was include the dequeue() function at the end of the function I passed to queue().

Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: you need a style of "position: relative;"  or "position: absolute;" added to your CSS.

I tried to run the code, but saw nothing.  However, when I used Firebug's HTML tab to look at the page, I saw most of them had a style="left: 140px" or similar.

Comment: thanks for the guess -- unfortunately that's not it. I've included my CSS code now in case there are any clues in there.

Comment: Interesting that it worked for you, though. I'll try isolating this function from my other code and bug-fixing that way.

Comment: It seems to work on Google Chrome as well. Maybe we need to see more context to know what's going wrong in your case.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what David said about the positioning. Your sections should probably be positioned absolutely inside a relatively positioned div. Also, I don't think you need the jQuery/Queue method. Try this instead:

```
$(".section.active").each(function() {
    $(this).show("slow", function() {
    $(this).animate({ "left": left }, "slow");
    left += $(this).width() + margin;
    });                
});
```

This will cause the animate left to be called after the show slow. I don't know how you are processing the show but when I used your same pattern from the animate left in a separate function and then called one after the other, the animate function was not being called at all from inside the second queue function.

Based on what I read in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) it looks like all animation functions are automatically added to the built-in fx queue.